# Nutx 3 layout transitions not working. Why?

Tags: layout, vuejs3, transition, nuxt3

I'm developing a project with Nuxt 3 and Vue 3 and I'm experiencing an issue with layout transitions: they're not working and the page stays blank.
I created a Stackblitz for you to check the issue I'm experiencing: [https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/elisabetperez/nuxt-layouts](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/elisabetperez/nuxt-layouts)

I've got two layouts: full and sidenav. I've got two pages too: index.vue and library.vue. Each of them has the name of the layout they need defined in definePageMeta. In addition to this, nuxt.config.ts has the layoutTransition defined and the style of the transition is defined in app.vue just like the documentation states. What am I missing? Thanks!

Environment details:

- Operating System: Darwin
- Node Version: v16.19.0 Nuxt Version: 3.10.0
- CLI Version: 3.10.0 Nitro Version: 2.8.1
- Package Manager: npm@10.4.0
- Builder: - User
- Config: devtools, modules, sanity, css, supabase,
  app, vite
- Runtime Modules: @nuxtjs/supabase@1.1.6,
  @nuxtjs/sanity@1.8.3
- Build Modules: -

Reproduction
[https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/elisabetperez/nuxt-layouts](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/elisabetperez/nuxt-layouts)

Comment: Hi, stackblitz link is 404

Comment: hi @Reagan the link is working for me even on incognito. weird. https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/elisabetperez/nuxt-layouts

Comment: It's harder to track the issue since there are so many files in the project. But, I created a simple example with the same content and the transition effect works
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-impeow?file=app.vue

Comment: thank you so much! deleting what specific thing made the trick for you @Reagan? I'm seeing yours working and mine not working with the same code, so something must be interfering